# achieve "order by" before "group by" in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a DB with this structure

**id, UserID, price, Date**

```
,1, 10.00, 2000-01-01
,1, 25.00 ,2022-02-01
,2, 12.00 ,2000-01-05
,2, 13.00 ,2001-01-05
,2, 24.00 ,2022-01-01
,3, 23.00 ,2022-01-01
```

i want to show the price for each user based on newest date.
So just 1 row per UserID (latest date)

if we query above table. results need to be like this:

```
    ,1, 25.00 ,2022-02-01
    ,2, 24.00 ,2022-01-01
    ,3, 23.00 ,2022-01-01
```

i have tried those 2 commands but they are not working

> SELECT UserID,price,Datee FROM (SELECT UserID,price,Datee FROM tbl
> ORDER BY UserID ASC,datee DESC) as tb_temp  GROUP BY UserID

also this

> SELECT UserID,price,max(Datee) FROM tbl Group by UserID ORDER BY UserID ASC,datee DESC

this command show latest date but price is not based on that

so i need something like **ORDER BY datee then group by userID**  or  L**IMIT 1 per userID**

Comment: does your table have a primary key (id) column, or only UserID, price and Datee?

Comment: it have Auto increase id as primary key  "ID"

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you on? You can check with `select version()`

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.65-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: My approach won't work then as window functions weren't in MySQL before version 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, it's not the most efficient because it uses a sub-query:

```
SELECT t.UserID, t.price, t.Datee
FROM tbl t
JOIN tbl on t.id = (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE UserID = t.UserID ORDER BY Datee DESC LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY UserID
```

The idea is to join the table to itself by finding the latest row for the user id.

I made this sql fiddle to test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63d495/2

Answer (score 2):

If you're on MySQL 8, the most common way to achieve this is with a window function:

```
select userid, price, date
  from (select *
             , row_number() over (partition by userid 
                                      order by date desc) as row_priority
          from tbl
     ) subq
 where subq.row_priority = 1
```

[Here's a working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb37ba1e8339b217ead404e3235909a4)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a window function to good effect as MarcinJ has done--another approach would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
  S1.UserID,
  S1.price,
  S1.Date
FROM
  SampleDetails S1
WHERE
  S1.Date = (SELECT MAX(S2.Date) FROM SampleDetails S2 WHERE S2.UserID = S1.UserID GROUP BY S2.UserID);
```

You can try it out on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eP9ewfNPnxUFPYTM6cvEGJ/0).